# How to know which row was clicked (and access its data) in Grid in WP7?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanelDaily"
  Grid.Row="1"
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
     <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
     <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.Column="0"
     Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"
     Margin="0,0,0,0">
            First
   </TextBlock>
   <TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.Column="1"
     Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"
     Margin="0,0,0,0">
          Second
   </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

How can i detect which row was clicked in Tap event? I have tried to find `SelectedRow` or something like this but it seems there is no anything like this in Grid. Thank you very much.

Comment: A `Grid` control is simply a layout container and does not have any selection capabilities. You'd have to do some kind of messy workaround in the code-behind to find the Grid's child that contains the Clicked item, then look at the Grid.Row of that item. Have you considered using a `ListBox` and overwriting the `Template` if you're interested in selection capabilities? You may not even need that depending on what you're data you're interested in during the Click event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data into a button, and subscribe to on `OnClick` event.

```
<Button OnClick="evetnHandler">
<TextBlock Grid.Row="0"
     Grid.Column="0"
     Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"
     Margin="0,0,0,0">
            First
   </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

Also, as @Rachel said: you can use a ListBox.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Selected, Type=TwoWay}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
<DataTemlate>
    <TextBlock
         Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}"
         Margin="0,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And in a code-behind create

```
public ObservableCollection<DataItem> Items {get;set;}

private DataItem _selected;
public DataItem Selected
{
  get {return _selected;}
  set 
{
  _selected = value;
  //ha! item selected!!! handle it
}

}

public class DataItem 
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```